# AllScripts API HelloWorld

Tags: c#, authentication, licensing

I'm using the [*AllScripts* HelloWorld TouchWorks C# Project](http://developer.allscripts.com/Downloads), as provided on their site. I've also created a valid application, using the `svcUsername` and `svcPassword` on the *app.config* file to log and added my own `appName` instead of the default *web20*.

Didnt change anything else, tried with many different application ID's, all trying to log into the [default sandbox server in the example](http://twlatestga.unitysandbox.com/Unity/unityservice.svc) and some trying other sandboxes.

Regardless of what I do, I keep getting

> Error: Service Application not licensed on this server!

Despite this being a sandbox server, thus suppouseably accessable to all applications.

What did I do wrong?

**edit**: Tried to do the same in Slueth, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more simple than it seems. Sandbox servers DO require licenses. Talked with the staff, they're nice people, so they manually added me after a few explanations of my requirements.

Comment: Is there any other servers where I can test their apis? I am getting same error

Comment: @nilesh Not really. You can test it via the .net interface and see everything compiles up until the licensing point and integrating with them, but until you get your license, sadly, you have nothing you can do. Make sure you raise your issue to allscripts early - the earlier you do, the earlier you get the license.

Comment: Signing-up takes no time at all.